# Elasticsearch APM server too many active handles

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, apm

We have recently put apm agent for one of our high traffic apis written in Nodejs Restify. While monitoring using pm2 monit i see that the number of active handles has increased drastically which eventually ends up making API unavailable. This happened after we attached the apm agent to it. What can be done for this?

Comment: I haven't worked with APM, but looking at the docs, there are multiple tuning options you might want to look at (if you haven't already). Settings like maximum_concurrent_connections, queue size in the APM server etc and metrics_interval in the agents might need to be configured according to your setup.
You should post your agent and server configs as well as any APM server logs that might indicate some problem in the configuration. ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding Archit, i had already tweaked all of these for maximum as per our infrastructure and load. I figured it was a problem inside our application and not APM.